# Does Swift task run first or print() first when I tap my UIButton?

Tags: swift, concurrency, uibutton, race-condition, decodable

I am trying to understand what is going on in my code here.

I have a simple API call to open weahter API and that whenever the user taps the UIButton, it should call the api and get the data back from open weather.

Everything works as intended however, when I have my UIButton pressed, the print statement executed first before the Task closure. I'm trying to understand the race condition here

This is my code in viewController:

```
@IBAction func callAPIButton(_ sender: UIButton)  {

        Task {
            let weatherData =  await weatherManager.fetchWeather(cityName: "Seattle")
        }
        
    }
```

Here's the code for fetching the API:

```
struct WeatherManager{
    let weatherURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=someAPIKeyHere"
    
    func fetchWeather(cityName: String)  -> WeatherModel? {
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"

            let requestResult =  performRequest(urlString: urlString)
            return requestResult
    }
    
    func performRequest(urlString: String)  -> WeatherModel? {
        var weatherResult : WeatherModel? = nil
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            let task =  session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in
                
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    weatherResult = parseJSON(weatherData: safeData)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
        return weatherResult
    }
    
    func parseJSON(weatherData: Data) -> WeatherModel?{
        let decoder  = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: weatherData)
            print("this is in decodedData: \(decodedData)")
            let temp = decodedData.main.temp
            let name = decodedData.name
            let weather = WeatherModel(conditionId:300, cityName: name, temperature: temp)
            return weather
        } catch {
            print("Something is wrong here: "  + error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Here's my Model:

```
struct WeatherModel{
    let conditionId: Int
    let cityName: String
    let temperature: Double
    
    var temperatureString: String{
        return String(format: "%.1f", temperature)
    }
    
    var conditionName: String {
            switch conditionId {
            case 200...232:
                return "cloud.bolt"
            case 300...321:
                return "cloud.drizzle"
            case 500...531:
                return "cloud.rain"
            case 600...622:
                return "cloud.snow"
            case 701...781:
                return "cloud.fog"
            case 800:
                return "sun.max"
            case 801...804:
                return "cloud.bolt"
            default:
                return "cloud"
            }
        }
    
}
```

Desired result:

```
This is in weatherData: WeatherResponse(name: "Seattle", weather: [Awesome_Weather_App.WeatherAPI(description: "overcast clouds", icon: "04d")], main: Awesome_Weather_App.MainAPI(temp: 287.81, pressure: 1018.0, humidity: 44.0, temp_min: 284.91, temp_max: 290.42, feels_like: 286.48), sys: Awesome_Weather_App.SysAPI(sunrise: 1.6712886e+09, sunset: 1.6713243e+09))
```

This is what I am getting instead:

```
This is in weatherData: nil
this is in decodedData: WeatherResponse(name: "Seattle", weather: [Awesome_Weather_App.WeatherAPI(description: "overcast clouds", icon: "04d")], main: Awesome_Weather_App.MainAPI(temp: 287.81, pressure: 1018.0, humidity: 44.0, temp_min: 284.91, temp_max: 290.42, feels_like: 286.48), sys: Awesome_Weather_App.SysAPI(sunrise: 1.6712886e+09, sunset: 1.6713243e+09))
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your code makes no sense, and I'm surprised it compiles. You are saying `await weatherManager.fetchWeather` but `fetchWeather` is not `async` so this is pointless. In fact, _none_ of your code is `async`. So if I were you I would drop the Task entirely; it is a red herring. You're not doing `async/await` here at all.

Comment: I see only one print statement

Comment: What OS version are you targeting? If contemporary versions, I might suggest watching WWDC 2021 video [Use async/await with URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10095/).

Answer (score 1):

> Everything works as intended

No, it doesn't. I don't know why you claim such a thing; your code isn't working at all.

The problem is that you are trying to return `weatherResult` from `performRequest`. But `performRequest` gets its `weatherResult` value *asynchronously,* so this attempt is doomed to failure; you will always be returning `nil`, because the `return weatherResult`  happens *before* `session.dataTask` ever even starts to find out what `weatherResult` *is.*

Comment: I have a series of three very short articles starting [here](http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/) that explains this to you. I suggest you read them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just synchronously return the results of an asynchronous request. You have two basic options for asynchronous requests.

1. Use the older “completion handler” pattern with `Result` types:

   ```swift
   struct WeatherManager {
       let weatherURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
       let appId = "someAPIKeyHere"

       func fetchWeather(
           cityName: String,
           completion: @escaping (Result<WeatherModel, Error>) -> Void
       ) {
           guard var components = URLComponents(string: weatherURL) else {
               completion(.failure(URLError(.badURL)))
               return
           }
           components.queryItems = [
               URLQueryItem(name: "appid", value: appId),
               URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: cityName)
           ]

           guard let url = components.url else {
               completion(.failure(URLError(.badURL)))
               return
           }

           performRequest(url: url, completion: completion)
       }

       func performRequest(
           url: URL,
           queue: DispatchQueue = .main,
           completion: @escaping (Result<WeatherModel, Error>) -> Void
       ) {
           let session = URLSession.shared // note, do not create a new URLSession for every request or else you will leak; use shared instance

           let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
               guard
                   error == nil,
                   let data = data,
                   let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                   200 ..< 300 ~= response.statusCode
               else {
                   queue.async { completion(.failure(error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))) }
                   return
               }

               do {
                   let weatherResult = try parseJSON(weatherData: data)
                   queue.async { completion(.success(weatherResult)) }
               } catch {
                   queue.async { completion(.failure(error)) }
               }
           }
           task.resume()
       }

       func parseJSON(weatherData: Data) throws -> WeatherModel {
           let decoder = JSONDecoder()
           let response = try decoder.decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: weatherData)
           print("this is in decodedData: \(response)")
           return WeatherModel(conditionId: 300, cityName: response.name, temperature: response.main.temp)
       }
   }
   ```

   Then, rather than:

   ```
   let weather = weatherManager.fetchWeather(cityName: …)
   ```

   You would

   ```swift
   weatherManager.fetchWeather(cityName: …) { result in
       switch result {
       case .failure(let error):
           print(error)

       case .success(let weather):
           // do something with the `weather` object here
       }
   }

   // note, do not do anything with `weather` here, because the above
   // runs asynchronously (i.e., later).
   ```
2. Use the newer `async`-`await` pattern of Swift concurrency:

   ```swift
   struct WeatherManager {
       let weatherURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
       let appId = "someAPIKeyHere"

       func fetchWeather(cityName: String) async throws -> WeatherModel {
           guard var components = URLComponents(string: weatherURL) else {
               throw URLError(.badURL)
           }
           components.queryItems = [
               URLQueryItem(name: "appid", value: appId),
               URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: cityName)
           ]

           guard let url = components.url else {
               throw URLError(.badURL)
           }

           return try await performRequest(url: url)
       }

       func performRequest(url: URL) async throws -> WeatherModel {
           let session = URLSession.shared // note, do not create a new URLSession for every request or else you will leak; use shared instance

           let (data, response) = try await session.data(from: url)
           guard
               let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
               200 ..< 300 ~= response.statusCode
           else {
               throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
           }

           return try parseJSON(weatherData: data)
       }

       func parseJSON(weatherData: Data) throws -> WeatherModel {
           let decoder = JSONDecoder()
           do {
               let response = try decoder.decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: weatherData)
               print("this is in decodedData: \(response)")
               return WeatherModel(conditionId: 300, cityName: response.name, temperature: response.main.temp)
           } catch {
               print("Something is wrong here: "  + error.localizedDescription)
               throw error
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   And then you can do things like:

   ```swift
   Task {
       do {
           let weather = try await weatherManager.fetchWeather(cityName: …)
           // do something with `weather` here
       } catch {
           print(error)
       }
   }
   ```

---

Note, a few changes in the above unrelated to the asynchronous nature of your request:

- Avoid creating `URLSession` instances. If you do, you need to remember to invalidate them. Instead, it is much easier to use `URLSession.shared`, eliminating this annoyance.
- Avoid building URLs with string interpolation. Use `URLComponents` to build safe URLs (e.g., ones that can handle city names like “San Francisco”, with spaces in their names).